# stuck with [: too many arguments

Tags: shell, arguments

the process of file deletion is fail with initial if else method and keep showing the same error which was like 'too many arguments'
Any help is appreciated

```
if [ "$year" -a -eq -d "${var:0:4}" ];  then
   dir = "$folder/$subfolder/$sub/$sub" 
     if [ "$month" -a  -ge -d "${var:4}" ];  then
         command $dir
     fi
elif [ "$year" -a  -gt -d "${var:0:4}" ]; then  
        command $dir
    else 
        echo "NOT VALID"
    fi
```

Comment: What is the exact error message ( with line no ) ?

Comment: hi blackpearl, below is the error looks like..line number is consider for first line in the code above

 line 143: [: too many arguments

Comment: Since the code you have posted is not complete, what is the matching line number in this piece of code?

Comment: the error started at first line number  in the code

Comment: Can you post the value of year and and var?

Comment: year = 2019 var= 2019. The idea here is first i will request user to send the parameter for year and month an the code is looks like this var=$1. Then after user keyin the required parameter i will extract the value given by using this ${var:0:4) to get a year and $(var:4) to get a month.

Comment: to be clear the idea is im preparing simple shell script to allow user select and delete their data base on the given year and month.

Comment: sry just realize that -a is not require because -eq is already there.. - d im using it to define directory

Comment: Removing the flags should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unecessary flags.

```
if [ "$year" -eq "${var:0:4}" ];  then
    dir = "$folder/$subfolder/$sub/$sub" 
    if [ "$month" -ge "${var:4}" ];  then
        command $dir
    fi
elif [ "$year" -gt "${var:0:4}" ]; then  
    command $dir
else 
    echo "NOT VALID"
fi
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately new error is there starting from first line of the code [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Remove the -d flag.

Comment: @zz10 If you are getting that from line 1 here, it means one of the variables is empty.